# Can not use Laravel tests with only 'phpunit' commande

Tags: laravel, phpunit

I have tried to test my **Laravel** application using the command

`phpunit`

But not success, I get the following message:

> No tests executed!

But it works fine when I use:

`.\vendor\bin\phpunit`

> Tests: 2, Assertions: 2, Failures: 1.

NB: I'm using the default **Laravel 5.7.0** configuration and all my test classes ends with `Test.php`.

### Question:

How can I configure Laravel correctly to use just the `phpunit` command to run all my test suites?

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to use the command `phpunit`, install PHPUnit globally and define the path.

```
composer global require phpunit/phpunit
composer global require phpunit/dbunit
```

Then you add this to your `~/.bashrc` or `~/.profile`

```
export PATH=~/.composer/vendor/bin:$PATH
```

This approach has the downside of always testing with the same version of PHPUnit without testing with the one defined by the project composer.json file. Therefore, using `./vendor/bin/phpunit` is the better way.

Comment: How can I do if I'm using Windows?

Comment: I did install it globally but no success

Comment: The absolute path that you use will be like the following (check it), replacing USERNAME with your username: C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Roaming\Composer\vendor\bin To add the absolute path to your %PATH% variable go to User Accounts under your Control Panel and then with your user account selected, click on Change my environment variables.

Comment: Check this https://www.photogabble.co.uk/blog/tools-and-resources/how-to-set-composer-bin-path-in-windows/

Comment: I did try this but no success, I've found that the path has been already declared in my environment variables, but always i get no tests executed :/